# parse dates with milliseconds in pandas read_csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, parsing

My `.csv` looks like this:

```
     date      time  
0    20190101  181555700  
1    20190101  181545515
```

where the format is `YYYYMMDD` for `date` and `HHMMSSMMM` for `time` (last MMM are milliseconds). For example the first row would be `2019-01-01 18:15:55.700`

Is there a way to parse this directly from `pd.read_csv()` without having to convert it later? Using only `parse_dates` does not work as it doesn't recognize the format. What I would like is to have a single column in my dataframe, with the timestamp correctly parsed like

```
    timestamp
0   2019-01-01 18:15:55.700
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve. Are you saying you want the dataframe to convert each of date and time to  time stamps and keep them in separate fields?

Comment: I added some details, I hope it's clear now!

Comment: Since your `date` and `time` are two separate columns, you may not be able to do so with `read_csv`. You can probably make do with `read_fwf` but I'm not entirely sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is close to what you need:

```py
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

data = pd.read_csv(
   './a.csv',
   delimiter='\t',
   index_col=0,
   parse_dates=[1],
   converters={'time': lambda t: dt.datetime.strptime(t, '%H%M%S%f').time()}
)
```

Output:

```
        date             time
0 2019-01-01  18:15:55.700000
1 2019-01-01  18:15:45.515000
```

After some survey I found this:

```
data = pd.read_csv(
   './a.csv',
   delimiter='\t',
   index_col=1,
   parse_dates={'datetime': [1, 2]},
   converters={'time': lambda t: dt.datetime.strptime(t, '%H%M%S%f').time()}
)
```

And the output is:

```
                 datetime
0 2019-01-01 18:15:55.700
1 2019-01-01 18:15:45.515
```

Comment: this way it works! Had no idea how `converters` worked

Comment: I think `pd.read_csv` will do `converter` on `time` column first, then merge `date` and `time` according to `parse_dates` argument.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `to_timedelta` with `unit` option to turn your `time` into `timedelta` and add to `date`:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', parse_dates=['date'])
df['date'] = df.date + pd.to_timedelta(df.time, unit='ms')
```

or:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date) + pd.to_timedelta(df.time, unit='ms')
```

Output:

```
                     date       time
0 2019-01-03 02:25:55.700  181555700
1 2019-01-03 02:25:45.515  181545515
```

**Update** per comment:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date.astype(str)+df.time.astype(str), format='%Y%m%d%H%M%S%f')
```

Output:

```
                     date       time
0 2019-01-01 18:15:55.700  181555700
1 2019-01-01 18:15:45.515  181545515
```

Comment: thanks, I knew this but I was wondering it there was a way to do it directly from `pd.read_csv()`

Comment: I'm wondering `181555700` should be `18:15:55.700`, but the output is `02:25:55.700`?